# Реализация text + select

Tags: javascript

Есть поле типа text, в нем разрешено вводить только цифры.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('input').onkeyup = function(){
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
  };
};
</script>
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

Необходимо: после ввода цифры ниже должно появиться изображение нажав на которое появится поле select с вариантами выбора для заданной цифры.
Пример: введена цифра 1, ниже появилось изображение, нажали, открылось поле select с вариантами выбора: текст1, текст2... Для цифры 2 аналогично кроме вариантов выбора.
Как реализовать?

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Не знаю как вывести изображение ниже после ввода цифры

Comment: покажите как сами пробовали. и куда выводить

Comment: Вы сами хоть пробовали сделать?

Comment: К сожалению я не знаю js, но нужно сделать сегодня, поэтому прошу помощи... Есть текстовое поле вводим число и в зависимости от числа выводим соответствующее изображение ниже под полем типа text.

Comment: @exavier, вы видимо сайтом ошиблись. Если хотите, чтобы сделали **за вас** -- вам на биржу фрилансеров.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, мне нужно понять принцип реализации, а не готовый код)

Comment: @AlexDemonov, а как вы, простите, будете превращать принцип реализации в готовый код не зная JavaScript?)

Answer (score 4):

Подход к решению задачи должен быть таким:

На событие `change` поля ввода добавляется обработчик. Этот обработчик создает `HtmlElement` для изображения, причем атрибут `src` этого элемента выставляется в зависимости от значения поля ввода. Полученный элемент, вставляется в DOM дерево документа в нужное место.

Код писать не буду принципиально, потому что автор в комментарии просит объяснить принцип. Можете минусовать =)